# NightWatch - unable to find element with xpath locator on an input with value

Tags: node.js, selenium, xpath, nightwatch.js

With nightwatch, I have issues to find an element on my page, The XPATH is GOOD, because I a have find it with FirePath.

My page code :

```
<label class="switch " data-ng-repeat="item in values">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" 
name="obtentionPermisConduiteAccompagneeSwitcher" value="N" ng-
model="$parent.model" ng-required="!$parent.model" required="required" 
type="radio"/>
```

......

My selector:

```
input_conduiteAccompagnee: {
selector: './/input[@name="obtentionPermisConduiteAccompagneeSwitcher" and @value="N"]',
locateStrategy: 'xpath'
},
```

My command :

```
//conduite accompagnee
onglet_conducteur.waitForElementVisible('@input_conduiteAccompagnee', 
10000);
onglet_conducteur.click('@input_conduiteAccompagnee');
browser.pause(3000);
```

But I have the message :

× Timed out while waiting for element  to be visible for 10000 milliseconds.  - expec
ted "visible" but got: "not visible"

Have you already have the same issue ?

Comment: it might be helpful to see your test script code.  When you watch the test running, is the item actually visible?  Maybe you'll need to actually scroll to it first (I occasionally encounter situations when I need to force a scroll to the element)

Comment: The element is lower in the page.

Answer (score 0):

@ Ratnadip,

It return 1 element by XPATH.
But I think you have right concerning the scrolling because my element is lower in the page..

I tried some thinks like :

```
onglet_conducteur.getLocationInView('@select_conduiteAccompagnee', 
function(result) {
this.execute('scrollTo(result.value.x, result.value.y)');
this.execute('scrollIntoView');
});
```

but it does not work.

Thanks